# Is there a way in WordPress to go back to default settings, delete all assets, etc.?

Tags: wordpress

I'm a WordPress n00b and have a question that may be a stupid one. Basically, I want to start my site from scratch, but want to keep all the plugins and themes that I downloaded. Is this possible, and if so, what are the steps to do it?

Comment: just change to a new db in wp-config?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new database and update this value in `wp-config.php`, it will initialise your posts, users, etc...

The plugins in the plugins folder and themes in themes folder will still remain although you might need to reconfigure the theme.

Comment: Is it possible for me to just delete the current database and create a new one with the same name?

Comment: yes. wordpress should prompt that database needs to be configured.